# python rpc/soap/json/wsdl binding

Tags: python, json, soap, mono, wsdl

I want to call methods and get/set instance variables on an instance of a given python class from another process.  All of the class methods and variables accept/return simple python dictionaries or lists (specifically it is the [P4Python API](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html) - I can't use the perforce c++ interop and need the option to call this from another host)

I'd like do this via SOAP or passing json back and forth. My first target is to have mono consume the python class.  I am toying with the idea of writing my own bindings generator using python's inspect module that would spit out c# files for my python class.

Have I missed anything out there that already lets me do this? [pywebsvcs looks quite close](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html)! Could I generate a wsdl file from this?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be SOAP or JSON? I think something similar is quite simple with xmlrpc (which comes with python). I'm using it a lot.

Comment: ooh perhaps, I was aiming for json as it is less verbose on the wire.